# uncaught type error: can not read length is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql

In the below JavaScript code cannot read length of undefined error please find out (I want take json array database values to print as a table format with image)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('#opt2').click(function() {
        alert($(this).attr('id')); //-->this will alert id of checked checkbox.
        if (this.checked) {
          $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/secondpage/sorting",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
              var jsonObj = data;
              $('#tbody').append('');
              n = jsonObj.rooms.length;
              for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                var eachrow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + jsonObj.rooms[i].image_url + "</td>" + "<td>" + jsonObj.rooms[i].name + "</td>" + "<td>" + jsonObj.rooms[i].location + "</td>" + "<td>" + jsonObj.rooms[i].price + "</td>" + "</tr>";
                $('#tbody').append(eachrow);
              }
            }
          });
        }
      });
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tbody">
  </tbody>
</table>
```

y it should like the error will come in JavaScript file

and also how to display image with database(i.e phpmyadmin) in JavaScript file 
     please find out immediately i want answer quickly help me out

Comment: have you confirmed the json object is actually a json object? Can you post the full json here to check that `jsonObj.rooms.length` is correct

Comment: ya the above code is as same but the output is showing in console.log file but i want it displays table format but json objects are not serial

Comment: [{"name":"incrave","location":"hyderabad","hotel_code":"0123","image_url":"image2.jpg","room_code":"12340","num_bed":null,"comfort_level":"standard","max_capacity":"0","fee":null,"price":"100","type":"single"}

Comment: array values is like this how i can write json object values

Comment: Provided object does not have `rooms` property..

Comment: kk i got but how to show in table format with javascript

Comment: how to given image path to json object

Comment: Edit main question with full json array. That doesn't even have room property so of course json object.rooms won't work.

Comment: its working but i want how to add image path to objects

Comment: So you are saying there is no error regarding the length? `cannot read length of undefined error`

Comment: yes  but how to image path in json obj please help me

Comment: @purender your request doesn't really make sense. so there is no error, what output are you getting atm? What are you expecting? if the for loop is running fine, I don't understand.. you are accessing the image_url correctly (given that the json is correct as you are saying there are no errors)

Comment: no errors means it showing table format with values but image_url means it is also database name now i want display image with an image src not image name as it is in database field@Matt

Comment: Can't you just do `<td><img src='" + jsonObj.rooms[i].image_url + "'></td>` if i am misunderstanding I'm sorry.

Comment: ya i got img source but it not displaying image how to add path

Comment: i ask one question:I want if i click the checkbox it displays data then i click the radio button checkbox data will remove then displays radio button please  help me how it is